# Taking backups from a local server to a remote server

Tags: mysql, backup

I have a mysql database that i would like to take a backup and send it to a remote server.

I am getting the following error:
180227 05:53:09  version_check Connecting to MySQL server with DSN 'dbi:mysql:;mysql_read_default_group=xtrabackup' (using password: NO).
Failed to connect to MySQL server: DBI connect(';mysql_read_default_group=xtrabackup','',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at - line 1315.
180227 05:53:09 Connecting to MySQL server host: localhost, user: not set, password: not set, port: not set, socket: not set
Failed to connect to MySQL server: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).

I am using percona Xtrabackup.How can I solve this?

The local server uses Ubuntu(version 16.04) and the remote server uses Red Hat Enterprise Linux(version 7.3).

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: So what's the problem? Just create backup and copy them to the remote server using scp or any other way.

Comment: i am getting the following error:

Comment: 180227 05:53:09  version_check Connecting to MySQL server with DSN 'dbi:mysql:;mysql_read_default_group=xtrabackup' (using password: NO).
Failed to connect to MySQL server: DBI connect(';mysql_read_default_group=xtrabackup','',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at - line 1315.
180227 05:53:09 Connecting to MySQL server host: localhost, user: not set, password: not set, port: not set, socket: not set
Failed to connect to MySQL server: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).